# Product of the reaction between chalcone and sodium methoxide in methanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

[image: Chalcone and sodium methoxide in methanol]

I'm a bit lost on how to do this, for Product **C** I can see two things happening:

1) The $\ce{-OCH3}$ attacks the alpha hydrogen, but that doesn't really make sense as then you would get two double bonds next to one another

2) The $\ce{-OCH3}$ attacks the electrophilic carbon, but then we know the negatively charged oxygen cannot collapse back because then the $\ce{-OCH3}$ would leave. So, would it just get printed by $\ce{HOCH3}?$ And if it does that how would it react with the second set of reactions?

Comment: $\ce{-OCH3}$ will attach on $\beta$ carbon, then keto-enol tautomerization would occur. Finally bromination at $\alpha$ carbon will be there.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is called *Michael addition*. Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_reaction) wikipedia page.

> The Michael reaction or Michael addition is the nucleophilic addition of a carbanion or another nucleophile to an α,β-unsaturated carbonyl compound. A newer definition, proposed by Kohler, is the 1,4-addition of a doubly stabilized carbon nucleophile to an α,β-unsaturated carbonyl compound.

Of course, in your case, the nucleophile is $\ce{OCH3-}$. Perform 1,4-addition by adding it to the double bond at the beta position (with respect to the carbonyl), and you'll expect an enolate ion, which looks like this -

> [image]

Finally protonate the $\ce{O-}$ and tautomerise to get your product as @Zenix already stated.

For the second step, check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketone_halogenation) link.

> [image]

**References:** [*Michael reaction, wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_reaction) || [*Ketone halogenation, wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketone_halogenation) || [*Enol, wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enol)

Comment: So for question 6 would I just be getting the same product again?

Comment: @user690808 Nope, I'm not sure if you got the idea. For question 6, the answer would be 3-methoxy-1,3-phenyl-propan-1-one.

Comment: Im still a bit confused could you draw a mechanism of the first reaction for me.